# Pagination on nested arrays (attributes)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Im trying to follow the "one table" principle in my nosql db model for a social network. But it throws many questions on me. 
Lets say my model right now looks like this:

```
Table-Groups
{
  name: "Group1"
  topics: [
    name: "Topic1"
    posts: [
      {
        id: "tid1"
        author: "Walter White"
        message: "Hello from Post1"
        comments: [
          {
            id: "cid1"
            author: "Jessy"
            message: "Yo nice post Mr. White"
          }
          {
            id: "cid2"
            author: "Saul"
            message: "Jeze Walt"
          }
        ]
      }
      //... Many other posts here    
    ]
      //... Many other topics within the group
  ]
}
//... Not so many other groups
```

***Would I be able to paginate the post or comments array?***

Since I would have (in theory) a lot of posts in the post array, I would have to read a lot of data where I actually just wanted to read the latest 10 posts. Same goes with the array comments in a post. Is there any possibilty to paginate these arrays ?

***Can I use the attribute "name" in the topic array as sortKey ? (topic.name)***

Is there any way to use an attribute of an nested array as a sort key ? In my example there are many topics in a group. So it would make sense to use topic names as sort keys (or even Partition key If I am allowed to split the table).

I have the feeling that I should split the Table in at least two. With that I could use topicname as partitionkey and group name as sort key. But Im realy new to nosql dbs and what I learned is that you should only use one table. What is your opinion ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would I be able to paginate the post or comments array?

No. Your model has a single item you call Group. When your server runs GetItem, all topics are returned for you, and, inside topics, all comments too.

There is another big problem in your model: your group can increase indefinitely and the max size of a DynamoDB item is 400 KB. Check [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html):

**"The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the size limit."**

In other words, at some time, you won't be able to save more topics or posts.

> Can I use the attribute "name" in the topic array as sortKey ? (topic.name)

No. Check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey). It states: **"Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such restrictions for other, non-key attributes."**

> I have the feeling that I should split the Table in at least two. With that I could use topicname as partitionkey and group name as sort key.

I don't think you should split into two tables. You could model you DynamoDB in this way and keep with only one table:

1. Use `hashKey` and `sortKey` in your table.
2. Save your Groups items like this:

   - hashKey: group (it's string `group` and not a variable)
   - sortKey: `groupId`
   - name: `groupName`
3. Save your topics items this way:

   - hashKey: `groupId`
   - sortKey: `topicId`
   - name: `topicName`
4. Save your posts items like this:

   - hashKey: `topicId`
   - sortKey: `postId`
   - author: `author`
   - message: `message`
5. Save your comments items this way:

   - hashKey: `postId`
   - sortKey: `commentId`
   - author: `author`
   - message: `message`

With that, if you want to retrieve a single item, you run a GetItem with the full key: `hashKey` and `rangeKey`.

Instead, if you want to query with pagination, you provide only `hashKey` in your query and limit it by 10 as you want ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-Limit) about query limits).

Finally, if you want to query by time, the most recent in your case, you could prefix your sort keys with date/time. For instance, `2019-08-11-22-03-03_SOME_STRING`. Check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html) about query using time.

Comment: This is what I searched for. Thank you for that. But I'm thinking about likes now. How could I manage the likes of a post ?

Answer (score 0):

Like the other comment by Pedro said, you'll quickly fall into the issue of your item size being >400KB.

The whole point of a nosql database like dynamodb is that you should be able to model your system (regardless of how complex) into a single table. There is however no restriction on the table, but you should be able to model your current requirement using a single table.

Try to separate out groups, topics, posts & comments and use their ids as partitions keys. To implement pagination, you could query posts with a [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Limit)
You could implement your table like how the other commenter has specified, and maybe add GSIs if you need different type of queries.